# Question on images

Tags: functions

so suppose we have a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. If I wanted to find the image of, $(-1,1)$ I would get that $f((-1,1)) = (\frac{1}{2},1]$ right? In comparison to the interval $(-3,4)$ would I get $f((-3,4)) = (\frac{1}{10},1]$. I learned this stuff a long long time ago, and I wanted some brief review on it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you found the image $f:  (3, 4) $? What was your thought process? What is $f(3)$?

Comment: well the way I thought about it was just to plug in the values for $x$ and then whatever yielded the smallest and largest values were the bounds for the interval. I think I'm wrong, but $f(3) = \frac{1}{10}$?

Comment: You have to plug in every value in the domain. EG Since $f(3) = 1/10$, then should $1/10$ be in the image?

Comment: I would think that it is in the image yes

Comment: So, how would you modify your answer to $f: (3,4)$? What other values are you missing? For such questions, it is often helpful to draw a graph.

Comment: I see what you mean, but to clarify, the image of an interval will just be another interval of values right? I think I see what you mean. I think that the actual image of $(3,4)$ would be $(\frac{1}{17},1]$. because I wasn't considering the 4 value.

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on the function. EG If the function is $f(x) = 1$ if $ x \neq 0$, and $f(x) = 0 $ if $ x = 0 $, then what is the image of $f : (-1, 1)$?   If you're restricting yourself to continuous functions, then yes the image of an interval is an interval.  $\quad$ Yes, the image of $ (3, 4) $ is $ ( 1/17, 1 ] $.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on that one, but I'm leaning more towards the image of $f(-1,1) = 0$.

Comment: What is $f(0.5)$ in my example?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, $f(0.5) = 1$. So would we just get 1 if $x \neq 0$ and 0 if $x = 0$

Comment: So the image is the 2 elements $ \{ 0, 1 \}$, which isn't an interval.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!